# jquery html or innerHTML?

Tags: jquery

why i am unable to display the text in my dev box?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("facebookUserBox").innerHTML("you have not loggged in...")
    });

    var loggedIn = '<%=IsLoggedIn%>'
    if (loggedIn) 
    {
        $("facebookUserBox").innerHTML("Logged in text");
    } 

</script>


<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="facebookUserBox"></div> 
<br />
<br />

   User Id:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    Password: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: i am not sure my jquery alignment is messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("facebookUserBox")` should be `$("#facebookUserBox")`

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix your jQuery selector with `#` to tell it you're selecting an element by ID.

```
$("#facebookUserBox")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is jQuery, not prototype
use `$("#facebookUserBox")` instead of `$("facebookUserBox")`

Answer (score 1):

```
#facebookUserBox
```

In PrototypeJS you would use that selector, jQuery uses CSS selectors for $() function